# Generate Mathematica script with fontspec

Tags: fontspec

I am trying to generate this [character](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/ScriptCapitalW.html) from Mathematica using fontspec. I can generate an upright version, but want it slightly slanted so it matches the font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\usepackage[cal=txupr]{mathalpha}
%\usepackage[cal=mma]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{W}$
\end{document}
```

I tried adding the "cal=mma" option but it didn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: No, I assumed Overleaf would import it automatically... I downloaded Jens-Peer Kuska files but I can't figure out which ones do I need to load the font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solutions are often the best...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\usepackage[cal=pxtx]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{W}$
\end{document}
```

Not the same font, but it's very close.

Answer (score 2):

Since you’re using `unicode-math`, you need to find a font whose version of the symbol looks more like what you want.

You can get some font specimens [from the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf#14).  If, for example, you think the script alphabet from STIX Two Math looks better, you can add the line

```
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
  range={cal,bfcal},
  Scale=MatchUppercase ]
```

It’s relatively common for math fonts to have a second script alphabet as a stylistic set or alternative.  Unicode 13.0 has only one regular-weight Mathematical Script alphabet, which `unicode-math` uses for both `\mathcal` and `\mathscr`.  But, for example, STIX Two has two separate alphabets that [you can load through stylistic sets.](https://github.com/stipub/stixfonts/blob/master/docs/charts/StixTwoMath.pdf)

```
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math} % Includes \mathcal, \mathbfcal
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
   StylisticSet=1,
   range={scr,bfscr} ]
```

You can also load any script font of your choice instead of a math font, in which case you will get its Latin alphabet.  For example,

```
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Chorus}[
  range=cal, Scale=MatchUppercase]
```

Loading `\usepackage[cal=mma]{mathalpha}` is not going to work together with `unicode-math`, because `unicode-math` redefines all math symbols after the preamble is finished.  You could, however, redefine a symbol within `\AtBeginDocument` to get your hook in after `unicode-math` runs.  Even then, to use Mathematica fonts, you would need the commercial package.